# Terminology and explanation of Doctrine PDO

Tags: php, design-patterns, interface, doctrine

I have noticed an interesting technique Doctrine is using for for it's Connection and Statement interfaces.

They have a class called `PDOConnection`, which naturally extends `PDO`, but also implements Connection, an interface created by Doctrine.

The `Connection` interface defines copies of several PDO methods, and although Doctrines PDOConnection class doesn't implement all of them, the fact it extends PDO means it does.

My best guess why they did that is they wanted to design their connection drivers around PDO's methodology, but what I really what to know is what this pattern is called and if it regularly gets used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My best guess why they did that is they wanted to design their connection drivers around PDO's methodology

Yep, that's it. There is no special pattern for this.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking into using this method myself, but my initial reason was because the classes I am extending don't implement an interface of their own.  I am trying to investigate additional benefits for doing this.

Comment: `because the classes I am extending don't implement an interface of their own` Yep, that's another benefit. Although you could just extend them and make the sub class implementing the interface. However, it looks like you're thinking in the right directions.